# BeautifulSoup not finding tags 3

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

BeautifulSoup is not finding the div tag 'pl-price js-pl-price'. I see it in the inspect element, however when I run my code, my code returns 'None'. Div 'product-details' is also in the HTML and it is found. But, div tag 'pl-price js-pl-price' can't be found by beautifulsoup. Why is that?

My Code:

```
import urllib2, sys, requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site = "https://www.lowes.com/pl/Refrigerators-Appliances/4294857973?goToProdList=true"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = urllib2.Request(site,headers=hdr)
page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

details = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'product-details'})
name = details.find('p', attrs={'class': 'h6 product-title js-product-title met-product-title v-spacing-large ellipsis-three-line art-plp-itemDescription'}) 
price = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': "product-pricing"})
actual_price = price.find('div', attrs={'class': "pl-price js-pl-price"})

print actual_price
```

HTML FROM WEBSITE:

```
<div class="product-details">
 <div class="product-pricing">
  <div class="pl-price js-pl-price" tabindex="-1">
  <!-- Start of Product Family Pricing -->
  <!-- Map price and savings through date present for product family -->
```

RESULTS:

> scrape_products.py
>   None

Comment: How are you getting "HTML from website", is it the same as the `page` you're passing to bs4?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yea, it's the same page im passing to bs4

Comment: @jonrsharpe what I did was right click the website, and used inspect element to see what divs I wanted to access. BeautifulSoup can't seem to find the div with class "pl-price js-pl-price" that I am looking for. Apparently I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I'm not able to find that class attribute using `lxml`, nor can I find it using dev tools in Chrome

Comment: @C.Nivs For the first product on this page, right click on 'View Price In Cart' and click 'Inspect'. You should be now be in the div class = "v-spacing-mini" which is an inner div of class = "pl-price js-pl-price". Tell me if you see what im talking about.

Comment: That's **not** necessarily the same data you're passing to bs4. Have you actually looked at the content of `page`?

Comment: Ah, so if you are to click on that page, you are now looking at a different url. Are you looking to get the prices of *all* of the products on that search page?

Comment: AHHH @jonrsharpe you're absolutely correct. now, I guess my question is, how do I access the div class "pl-price js-pl-price"?

Comment: @C.Nivs yes, im attempting to get all the prices. I'm guess im confused --- the url in my code and the url of the page i right clicked on are different?

Comment: You need to read up more on web scraping, focusing on tools that help you with pages that load data using JavaScript/Ajax.

Comment: @DavidClarke Yep, as Steven's answer suggests, you'll need to interact with the website to get the prices by adding each item to your cart. This is also probably rendered via JavaScript, and thus is not immediately present in the html pulled by a `get` request. You'll need a browser session to access it

Comment: okay, that makese sense. How about the items that actually lists the price? (not "View item in cart".

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the results of the `price` search, you can see in the HTML the following text:

`"Since Lowes.com is national in scope, we check inventory at your local store first in an effort to fulfill your order more quickly. You may find product or pricing that differ from that of your local store, but we make every effort to minimize those differences so you can get exactly what you want at the best possible price."`

This would lead me to believe that the pricing information isn't loading immediately, and thus isn't loaded into the HTML that is parsed by BeautifulSoup. You should try a headless browser solution with Selenium.

Comment: I agree, this is the way. It also looks like the only way you can view the price is by physically adding the item to the cart. Selenium is able to interact with the website in this fashion